# Hide/show All Children Divs - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide all children divs (element_wrapper) of elements on page load using data-id and data-parent attribute values. I'm new to javascript so I don't really know how to do that. Just hide them on pageload then, I want to show/hide them by clicking the buttons. Thanks in advance.

THE SOURCE HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="1" data-parent="">
            <input class="toggler_btn" type="button" value="+/-" data-id="1" data-parent="">
            Main Office
            <input type="button" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="3" data-parent="1">
            <input class="toggler_btn" type="button" value="+/-" data-id="3" data-parent="1">
            Room 203
            <input type="button" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="6" data-parent="3">
            <input class="toggler_btn" type="button" value="+/-" data-id="6" data-parent="3">
            Table 2
            <input type="button" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="4" data-parent="1">
            <input class="toggler_btn" type="button" value="+/-" data-id="4" data-parent="1">
            Room 256
            <input type="button" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="7" data-parent="4">
            <input class="toggler_btn" type="button" value="+/-" data-id="7" data-parent="4">
            Table 3
            <input type="button" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="2" data-parent="">
            <input class="toggler_btn" type="button" value="+/-" data-id="2" data-parent="">
            Not So Main Office
            <input type="button" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="5" data-parent="2">
            <input class="toggler_btn" type="button" value="+/-" data-id="5" data-parent="2">
            Room 301
            <input type="button" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="8" data-parent="5">
            <input class="toggler_btn" type="button" value="+/-" data-id="8" data-parent="5">
            Table 13
            <input type="button" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

THE PAGE LAYOUT CODE:

```
@model List<Tree_List.Controllers.Element>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

@helper PopulateDivs(List<Tree_List.Controllers.Element> elements)
{
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        <div class="element_wrapper" data-id="@element.ID" data-parent="@element.PARNET_ID">
            <input class="toggler_btn" type="button" value="+/-" data-id="@element.ID" data-parent="@element.PARNET_ID">
            @element.NAME
            <input type="button" value="Add" />
            <input type="button" value="Edit" />
            <input type="button" value="Delete" />
            @if (element.CHILDS.Count() > 0)
            {
                @PopulateDivs(element.CHILDS);
            }
        </div>
    }
}

<script>

</script>

<div id="wrapper">
    @PopulateDivs(Model)
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your rendered html, not your view code. This looks like Razor so shouldn't be hard to do.

Comment: @Nathaniel Flick Posted the source html

Comment: `$('#wrapper > .element_wrapper').hide();` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your problem right, but from what I understand you want to show or hide your add/edit/delete by clicking +/- button.

In order to hide elements on load you can make this via css, but can also be done with javascript.
This is the css you need.

```
.element_wrapper input{
  display: none;
}
.element_wrapper input.toggler_btn{
  display: block;
}
.element_wrapper input.active{
  display: block;
}
```

And here is the functionality for the button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.toggler_btn', function(){
        $(this).siblings('input').toggleClass('active');
    });
})
```

Now let's see how it works. When you click on toggler_button you get all 'input' siblings of the button you clicked (this is because your html structure is like that) and toggle a class (if the input have the class, toggleClass will remove, otherwise will add it). Then you have to look back at the css I wrote. You can see there

```
.element_wrapper input.active{
      display: block;
    }
```

which will make your button appear when they have the active class. 
Hope you got it. If you have any question please leave a comment.

LE:

You have my example here: https://jsfiddle.net/jxm2v4bv/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=jxm2v4bv